# How do I unit test an Angular component with an NgRx Entity Service using Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I've recently upgraded to my project to use Angular 15.2.4, Jest 29.5, and NgRx 15.4.

My unit tests dealing with components containing NgRx Entity services have broken.

**This is the entity Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EntityCollectionServiceBase, EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory } from '@ngrx/data';
import { Site } from 'app/models/site.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SiteEntityService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Site> {
  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super('Site', serviceElementsFactory);
  }
}
```

**This is the component**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Site } from 'app/models/site.model';
import { SiteEntityService } from 'app/store/site-entity.service';
import { Breadcrumb } from 'app/theme/shared/components/breadcrumb/models/breadcrumb.model';
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'app/theme/shared/components/breadcrumb/services/breadcrumb.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-site-search-shell',
  templateUrl: './site-search-shell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./site-search-shell.component.scss'],
})
export class SiteSearchShellComponent implements OnInit {
  sites$: Observable<Site[]>;

  constructor(
    private siteEntityService: SiteEntityService,
    private breadCrumbService: BreadcrumbService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.sites$ = siteEntityService.entities$;
    this.breadCrumbService.add(new Breadcrumb('Sites', '/sites'));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.siteEntityService.getWithQuery('$sort_by=name');
  }

  addClicked(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/sites/create');
  }
}
```

**This is the non-working test**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockComponent } from 'ng-mocks';

import { SiteSearchDisplayComponent } from '../site-search-display/site-search-display.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'app/theme/shared/components/breadcrumb/services/breadcrumb.service';
import { SiteSearchShellComponent } from './site-search-shell.component';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { EntityCollection, EntityCollectionServiceBase, EntityCollectionServiceElements, EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory, EntityDefinitionService, EntityDispatcherFactory, EntitySelectors$Factory, EntitySelectorsFactory } from '@ngrx/data';
import { Site } from 'app/models/site.model';
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { SiteEntityService } from 'app/store/site-entity.service';

describe('SiteSearchShellComponent', () => {
  let component: SiteSearchShellComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SiteSearchShellComponent>;
  let service: SiteEntityService;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(
    async () => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
          SiteSearchShellComponent,
          MockComponent(SiteSearchDisplayComponent)
        ],
        providers: [
          SiteEntityService,
          {
            provide: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory,
            useValue: {
              methodsToFake: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {}),
            }
          },
          BreadcrumbService
        ],
        imports: [RouterTestingModule],
        teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }
      }).compileComponents();
      service = TestBed.inject(SiteEntityService);

      router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    });


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SiteSearchShellComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });



  test('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('should route to sites/create when addCreate event called', () => {
    jest.spyOn(component, 'addClicked');
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');
    component.addClicked();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.addClicked).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(navigateSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(navigateSpy).toBeCalledWith('/sites/create');      
  });
});
```

I get the error:

```
  ● SiteSearchShellComponent › should create

    TypeError: serviceElementsFactory.create is not a function

       6 | export class SiteEntityService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Site> {
       7 |   constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    >  8 |     super('Site', serviceElementsFactory);
         |     ^
       9 |   }
      10 | }
      11 |

      at new EntityCollectionServiceBase (node_modules/@ngrx/data/fesm2020/ngrx-data.mjs:2221:78)
      at new SiteEntityService (src/app/store/site-entity.service.ts:8:5)
      at Object.SiteEntityService_Factory [as factory] (ng:\SiteEntityService\ɵfac.js:5:10)
      at R3Injector.hydrate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:8031:35)
      at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:7919:33)
      at R3Injector.<anonymous> (node_modules/ng-mocks/webpack:/ng-mocks/libs/ng-mocks/src/lib/common/ng-mocks-global-overrides.ts:371:53)
      at R3Injector.this (node_modules/ng-mocks/webpack:/ng-mocks/libs/ng-mocks/src/lib/mock-service/helper.create-clone.ts:10:65)
      at TestBedImpl.inject (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs:24201:52)
      at Function.inject (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs:24060:37)
      at src/app/areas/sites/site-search/site-search-shell/site-search-shell.component.spec.ts:41:25
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:416:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:3728:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:415:56)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:173:47)
      at Object.wrappedFunc (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:4208:34)
```

I have changed the test from the previously working version to try to get it running with the new versions.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of work, I managed to get it working:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Site } from 'app/models/site.model';
import { SiteEntityService } from 'app/store/site-entity.service';
import { Breadcrumb } from 'app/theme/shared/components/breadcrumb/models/breadcrumb.model';
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'app/theme/shared/components/breadcrumb/services/breadcrumb.service';
import { SiteSearchShellComponent } from './site-search-shell.component';
import { createSpyObj } from 'jest-createspyobj';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MockComponent } from 'ng-mocks';
import { SiteSearchDisplayComponent } from '../site-search-display/site-search-display.component';

describe('SiteSearchShellComponent', () => {
  let component: SiteSearchShellComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SiteSearchShellComponent>;
  let siteEntityServiceSpy: jest.Mocked<SiteEntityService>;
  let breadCrumbServiceSpy: jest.Mocked<BreadcrumbService>;
  let routerSpy = {
      navigateByUrl: jest.fn(),
    } as Partial<Router> as jest.Mocked<Router>;


  beforeEach(async () => {
    siteEntityServiceSpy = {
      entities$: of([]),
      getWithQuery: jest.fn(),
    } as Partial<SiteEntityService> as jest.Mocked<SiteEntityService>;

    breadCrumbServiceSpy = {
      add: jest.fn(),
    } as Partial<BreadcrumbService> as jest.Mocked<BreadcrumbService>;

    routerSpy = {
      navigateByUrl: jest.fn(),
    } as Partial<Router> as jest.Mocked<Router>;

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SiteSearchShellComponent, MockComponent(SiteSearchDisplayComponent)],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: SiteEntityService, useValue: siteEntityServiceSpy },
        { provide: BreadcrumbService, useValue: breadCrumbServiceSpy },
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SiteSearchShellComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```